# Tkinter GUI Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I would like to pass to the textbox any operation (e.g.: 3+4) that I write in the entry box. Sadly I couldn't figure it out.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN

window=tk.Tk()
window.title('Calculator')
frame=tk.Frame(master=window,bg="PaleGreen",padx=10)
frame.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(master = window,padx = 10)
frame2.pack()
entry=tk.Entry(master=frame,relief=SUNKEN,borderwidth=3,width=30)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,ipady=2,pady=2)

def click(number):
    entry.insert(tk.END,number)

def equal():
    try:
        y=str(eval(entry.get()))
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(0,y)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!","Syntax Error")

def clear():
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)

result_label = tk.Label(text="Eredmény:",fg="green",bg="yellow")
result_label.pack()

TextB = tk.Text(master=frame2)
TextB.pack()
button_1=tk.Button(master=frame,text='1',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(1))
button_1.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=2)
button_2=tk.Button(master=frame,text='2',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(2))
button_2.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=2)
button_3=tk.Button(master=frame,text='3',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(3))
button_3.grid(row=3,column=2,pady=2)
button_4=tk.Button(master=frame,text='4',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(4))
button_4.grid(row=4,column=0,pady=2)
button_5=tk.Button(master=frame,text='5',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(5))
button_5.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=2)
button_6=tk.Button(master=frame,text='6',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(6))
button_6.grid(row=4,column=2,pady=2)
button_7=tk.Button(master=frame,text='7',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(7))
button_7.grid(row=5,column=0,pady=2)
button_8=tk.Button(master=frame,text='8',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(8))
button_8.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=2)
button_9=tk.Button(master=frame,text='9',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(9))
button_9.grid(row=5,column=2,pady=2)  
button_0=tk.Button(master=frame,text='0',padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click(0))
button_0.grid(row=6,column=0,pady=2)

button_add=tk.Button(master=frame,text="+",padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click('+'))
button_add.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=2)

button_subtract=tk.Button(master=frame,text="-",padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click('-'))
button_subtract.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=2)

button_multiply=tk.Button(master=frame,text="*",padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click('*'))
button_multiply.grid(row=1,column=2,pady=2)

button_div=tk.Button(master=frame,text="/",padx=15,pady=5,width=3,command=lambda:click('/'))
button_div.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=2)

btnC=tk.Button(master=frame,text="clear",padx=15,pady=5,width=12,command=clear)
btnC.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=2)

button_equal=tk.Button(master=frame,text="=",padx=15,pady=5,width=9,command=equal)
button_equal.grid(row=6,column=1,columnspan=3,pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `equal()` function to update the text box (TextB) with the entered operation. The code will be:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Calculator')
frame = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="PaleGreen", padx=10)
frame.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window, padx=10)
frame2.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(master=frame, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=3, width=30)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, ipady=2, pady=2)

def click(number):
    entry.insert(tk.END, number)

def equal():
    try:
        operation = entry.get()
        TextB.insert(tk.END, operation + "\n")  # Update the text box with the entered operation
        result = str(eval(operation))
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, result)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!", "Syntax Error")

def clear():
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)

result_label = tk.Label(text="Eredmény:", fg="green", bg="yellow")
result_label.pack()

TextB = tk.Text(master=frame2)
TextB.pack()

# Rest of your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

```
def equal():
    try:
        equation=entry.get()
        y=str(eval(equation))
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(0,y)
        TextB.insert(tk.END,f'{equation}={y}\n')
```

I added some formatting to the text being inserted to separate each entry from the previous one.

After looking at your code some more, I think you would be happier using a tk.Message widget instead of a tk.Text widget.

Here is the revised equal() function:

```
def equal():
    try:
        equation=entry.get()
        y=str(eval(equation))
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(0,y)
        TextB.configure(text=f'{equation}={y}')
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!","Syntax Error")
```

and here is the revised TextB creation

```
TextB = tk.Message(master=frame2,text='',width=200)
```

Hope this helps refine your calculator.  BTW: a calculator should allow for the input of the . character.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to pass to the textbox any operation (e.g.: 3+4) that I
> write in the entry box

Add on line 14 and 24. `TextB.insert(....`

```
def click(number):
    entry.insert(tk.END,number)
    TextB.insert(tk.END,number) # add this 
     

def equal():
    try:
        y=str(eval(entry.get()))
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(tk.END, y)
        TextB.insert(tk.INSERT, f'= {y}') # add this       
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!","Syntax Error")
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing if its okay with you. How could I pass written addition or subtraction to my textbox instead of the form that I have now?

Comment: Do u mean plus, minus and multiply?

Comment: yes, with a written method

Comment: I will be back tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!

Comment: Use this `cget`. `print(button_add.cget('text'))` . Btw, I'm running out of time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't do anything. Will you still be back tomorrow?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: Hello Toyota Supra, did you find any solution for my problem?

Comment: I had the same problem. My staff can't solve the problem.